# securing code and data in a shiny app hosted on AWS

Tags: r, security, authentication, amazon-ec2, shiny

I have a general query regarding securing stored data and code in a shiny app that is hosted on AWS ec2.

Problem statement: I have hosted a shiny app on my AWS server with a login screen. Hence the users who have the ID and password will be able to log in. The client who is using the app does not want me to see the data/reports, etc she stores in the app. On the other hand, I don't want my client to have access to the R code as well.

How can I achieve this?

-> If the app is hosted on my AWS server, I will be able to see all client data.

-> If I host the app on the client's server, then they will be able to see the code.

Right now, I am using an internal authentication mechanism where ID and passwords are saved inside the R code. I am also aware of `shinymanager` package for authentication. But these authentications don't solve data and code security stated above.

Request your assistance. Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:
Right now, I have separate folders in `www` for each client to save their respective data/reports etc. But I can access those folders if the app is hosted on my AWS server.

Comment: Are temporary files an option?

Comment: The client needs to store data/report so that she will be able to access it later. So I don't think temporary files are an option.

Comment: Then either encryption (with its caveats) or local storage for the client are the things that come to mind.

Comment: I have not thought about these options: I think for local storage, user has to first provide the path to save/extract the stored data. with this option, there will be problem when user wants to access from other computers or when the storage is corrupted.  Could you please provide any link to read on the other option i.e. encryption